# Query formatted value using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have to query a Date column with formatted values. Consider a scenario, same date with different timing "05/12/2012 02:00:00" and "05/12/2012 12:00:00". I have to query this collection such that resultant should have only date and not time "05/12/2012"(dd/MM/yyyy).

```
datasource.AsQueryable().Select("Date").Cast<object>().Distinct().ToList<object>();
```

I have used the above to get collection and i am not able to get the formatted collection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just juse the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of DateTime?

```
datasource.Select(d => d.Date.Date).Distinct()
```

I can't figure out what you're trying to do with the `Cast`.